# Swift Snapchat fetchSnapUserInfo() 'UserEntity' value not a resolved identity

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, snapchat

I am working on integrating Snapchat login into my iOS app, in Xcode. This is my current code, implementing an SCSDKLoginButton in my view controller:
(The error is highlighted with a comment)

```
import SCSDKLoginKit

var scLoginButton: SCSDKLoginButton!

let scLoginButton = SCSDKLoginButton()
scLoginButton.center = CGPoint(x: 200, y: 200)
view.addSubview(scLoginButton)



    @IBAction func loginButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    SCSDKLoginClient.login(from: self, completion: { success, error in

        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return
        }

        if success {
            self.fetchSnapUserInfo()
        }
    })
}


private func fetchSnapUserInfo(){
    let graphQLQuery = "{me{displayName, bitmoji{avatar}}}"

    SCSDKLoginClient
        .fetchUserData(
            withQuery: graphQLQuery,
            variables: nil,
            success: { userInfo in

                if let userInfo = userInfo,
                    let data = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: userInfo, options: .prettyPrinted),
                    let userEntity = try? JSONDecoder().decode(UserEntity.self, from: data) { // ERROR HERE

                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.goToLoginConfirm(userEntity)
                    }
                }
        }) { (error, isUserLoggedOut) in
            print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "")
    }
}
```

On the line where "// ERROR HERE" is added, I keep getting the error "Use of unresolved identifier 'UserEntity'". I directly copied and pasted that method from the Snapchat LoginKit tutorials, and I do not know how to fix it. Any help is very much appreciated :))

(btw my AppDelegate and info.plist files already have the required code implemented)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UserEntity is a model you should create it in your project, i think u forget to follow this step:
UserEntity.swift:

struct UserEntity {
    let displayName: String?
    let avatar: String?

```
private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case data
}

private enum DataKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case me
}

private enum MeKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case displayName
    case bitmoji
}

private enum BitmojiKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case avatar
}
```

}

extension UserEntity: Decodable {

```
init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    let data = try values.nestedContainer(keyedBy: DataKeys.self, forKey: .data)
    let me = try data.nestedContainer(keyedBy: MeKeys.self, forKey: .me)

    displayName = try? me.decode(String.self, forKey: .displayName)

    let bitmoji = try me.nestedContainer(keyedBy: BitmojiKeys.self, forKey: .bitmoji)
    avatar = try? bitmoji.decode(String.self, forKey: .avatar)
}
```

}